# Dynamic reconfigure default parameters

Tags: ros, rosparam, best-practices, dynamic-reconfigure, parameter-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am writing a node which accepts certain parameters. I would like to be able to pass them through a launch file, as well as make them dynamically reconfigurable.

What are the best practices regarding this? In particular:

- What happens if the value in the launch file is not the same as the default value in the `.cfg` file?
- Does it matter whether I register the dynamic reconfigure services before or after getting the parameters from the nodehandle using `getParam()`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28327/dynamic-reconfigure-default-parameters/) by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4954 on 2012-02-23

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-02-23**:
Doesn't dynamic_reconfigure initialize the values from the param server automatically?

**Comment by [Crusty](https://answers.ros.org/users/5011/crusty/) on 2014-04-14**:
It would, but in configurations with "use_sim_time" and "rosbag play foo.bag --clock --pause" and then stepping through the bag file for debugging you potentially run into problems because no spinning seems to take place on sim_time, so no ros::spin()-based callbacks are called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should already get the desired behavior for free. When you create the dynamic_reconfigure server in your node, it initializes the configuration in these steps:

- Load default values as defined in the `.cfg`.
- Query parameter server for each parameter, overwriting the default value if it's set.
- Clamp all parameters to the ranges defined in the `.cfg`.

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) with karma: 4336 on 2012-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 14

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PiotrOrzechowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/9741/piotrorzechowski/) on 2014-01-21**:
You're right!
Unfortunately the ROSNodeTutorialC++ (http://wiki.ros.org/ROSNodeTutorialC%2B%2B) is misleading: It reads the parameters "a", "b" and "message" explicitly from the parameter server even though they are included in the dynamic reconfigure callback...

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2014-01-21**:
That tutorial may very well be in error. Please open a separate question explaining the problem, so we can get it resolved, as explained in the note at the top of each tutorial page.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dynamic reconfiguration works fine for your use case.

When you register your callback, it gets invoked immediately with the values currently defined in the parameter server and a level of `0xffffffff`. Those initial values will include anything set in your launch file. You don't need to read the parameters yourself using `getParam()`.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-02-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5